# ProgressBar not showing at the end of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I have a problem with display progress bar to give an information for user that the application is loading a new data to show. I had watch and read so many solution about it. I quite success in load and display new data. But to display the progress bar not really success. It so frustrating to seek why my code wrong or where my mistake is. So here I am, need some help from some expert in this field.

I had use everything I found in internet. I'm giving type when it reach at the bottom of the list. But, when I debug the program, type that return a number for show the progress bar not call.

Here is the important part of my adapter :

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            header = false;
            return new NewsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_news, viewGroup, false));
        } else if (i == 2) {
            Log.d("END", "Bagian terakhir");
            return new LoadingViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_progress, viewGroup, false));
        } else {
            header = true;
            return new NewsGroupViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_group, viewGroup, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position > 0 && articleList.get(position).getPublishedAt().equals(articleList.get(abs(position - 1)).getPublishedAt())) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(articleList.get(position) == null){
            return 2;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof NewsViewHolder) {
            NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder = (NewsViewHolder) viewHolder;
            newsViewHolder.bind(articleList.get(i));
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) viewHolder;
            loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof NewsGroupViewHolder) {
            NewsGroupViewHolder newsGroupViewHolder = (NewsGroupViewHolder) viewHolder;
            newsGroupViewHolder.bind(listDate.get(i), articleList.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Below is the way I load my data in my MainActivity :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if(newsPresenter.isListItemDisplaying(recyclerView) && !newsAdapter.isSearching()){
//                    if(loadMore!=null){
//                        loadMore.onLoadMore();
//                    }
                    allArticle.add(null);
                    newsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(allArticle.size()-1);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            allArticle.remove(allArticle.size()-1);
                            newsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(allArticle.size());
                            Log.d("LAST_ITEM","loadmore "+totalPages);
                            totalPages++;
                            List<Article> newArticle = new ArrayList<>();
                            newArticle.addAll(newsPresenter.loadEverything("android&page="+totalPages));
                            isLoading = true;
                        }
                    },PERIOD_MS);
                }
            }
        });
```

And some code to know if I reach the end of RecyclerView :

```
public boolean isListItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        if(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()!=0){
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if(lastVisibleItemPosition!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Below is XML file for ProgressBar :

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here some part of my XML file for MainActivity :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative_slider"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/headline_vp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/headline_vp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.tokopedia.testproject.problems.news.view.VerticalRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_slider"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_news"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I hope for the progress bar to show every time reach bottom of recyclerview. Thanks for your time and help. Ask me if you need some explanation.

Comment: What is value of PERIOD_MS?

Comment: 5000, it use to show progress bar for 5 seconds

Comment: Can you please also provide the code for the view (.xml)

Comment: All of it? @T.Mas

Comment: It would help if you could provide the entire code of your activity and recyclerview adapter.

Comment: And just a comment, in getItemViewType, if(articleList.get(position) == null), this should be your first check. Otherwise your cuurent first if condition in the same block will fail.